# How can I create a websocket using the data im getting from another websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, server

Im using a node server to get data from an websocket and I want to create my own websocket and send the data to a react app. Does anyone know any methods or packages for it.

Comment: you can use socket.io for that. https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: You set up a webSocket server in your nodejs server and then your react app can connect to it.  Once the client has established the webSocket connection, your server can freely send data to the client whenever it wants to.

Answer (score 0):

So I do something like your question.

**NODE.js side**

I used the socket.io library for sending data to my react app.
So for sending I use something like this.

```
    /*Declaration and settings up (you can replace the port)*/
        const express = require('express');
        const app = express();
        let server = require('http').Server(app);
        let io = require('socket.io')(server);
        server.listen(8081); //PORT of your socket
        app.listen(8080); //PORT of your API 
        /*If you want to do something when a user is connect you can do something like this 
        "topic" is a string, you can replace by what you want. Here the client (REACT) is 
        listening on  "topic"*/
        io.on('connect', (socket) => {
          let messageToSend = {
            "message": "Hello world!"
          };
          socket.emit("topic", messageToSend);
        });
        /*If you simply want to send something just use the io variable. like this*/
        io.emit("topic", "What you whant here");
```

**React side**

For react side I used socket.io-client

```
    import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
    /* insert the following code in a function or where you want.*/
    let client = socketIOClient("127.0.0.1:8081"); //ip of socket server
    /*After define client, you define the topic you want listening and the function you 
    want to use as callBack. Here I just print data*/
    client.on("topic", (data) => {
    console.log(data)});
```

You can find more details on the [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) and [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)

I hope my answer can be usefull.